# Yandex Карты: как поменять стили placemark с api 1.0 na 2.0

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

хочу перейти на 2.0,

```
var s = new YMaps.Style();
s.iconStyle = new YMaps.IconStyle();
s.iconStyle.offset = new YMaps.Point(-1, -30);
s.iconStyle.href = "http:www.example.com/images/1.png";
s.iconStyle.size = new YMaps.Point(29, 28);
s.iconStyle.shadow = new YMaps.IconShadowStyle();
s.iconStyle.shadow.offset = new YMaps.Point(2, -12);
s.iconStyle.shadow.href = "http:www.example.com/images/2.png";
s.iconStyle.shadow.size = new YMaps.Point(29, 7);
```

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите тут:

[Задание собственного изображения для иконки метки](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/icon_customImage)

```
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
    hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки'
}, {
    // Опции.
    // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    // Своё изображение иконки метки.
    iconImageHref: 'http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/images/myIcon.gif',
    // Размеры метки.
    iconImageSize: [30, 42],
    // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
    // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
    iconImageOffset: [-3, -42]
});
```